# Using Scanner to read in a text file

Tags: java

I have a text file with the following line define : `Hi 0x01.` I'm trying to read in the word `Hi` and store it in its own variables and `0x01` in its own variable.The problem I'm having is that i seem to be able to read in `Hi`, but  i can`t read in`0x01`.Here is my code

```
File comms =new File("src/Resources/com.txt");
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(comms)) {
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
                sc.useDelimiter("\\s+");
                try {
                  String comm1 = sc.next();
                 // System.out.println(comm1);
                 int value =sc.nextInt();
                 System.out.println(value);
                 sc.close();
                } catch (Exception ef){

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly have no idea what you're trying to do here. You'd better scan it once:

```
    File comms = new File("src/Resources/com.txt");
    try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(comms)) {
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            System.out.println(words[0]); // "Hi"
            System.out.println(words[1]); // "0x01"
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
```

Now, having these in separate strings you can do anything in the world with it like converting words[1] to int.